# Javascript unit test code coverage in TFS 2015

Tags: javascript, tfs, code-coverage, chutzpah

Does anyone have a solution to include Chutzpah code coverage in TFS build summary? The unit tests runs fine, but i dont get any code coverage. Our project has a DOD with an code coverage of 85%, so it would be great to automate this in the build process.

### Update

```
2016-01-12T07:58:08.5718428Z Executing the powershell script: D:\TFSAgent\tasks\VSTest\1.0.22\VSTest.ps1
2016-01-12T07:58:08.7749779Z ##[debug]Calling Invoke-VSTest for all test assemblies
2016-01-12T07:58:08.7905962Z Working folder: D:\TFSAgent\_work\6
2016-01-12T07:58:08.7905962Z Executing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe "D:\TFSAgent\_work\6\s\src\FSP.Tests\sampletests.js"  /Settings:"D:\TFSAgent\_work\6\s\buildtools\common.runsettings" /EnableCodeCoverage /logger:trx /TestAdapterPath:"D:\TFSAgent\_work\6\s\src\packages\Chutzpah.4.1.0\tools"
2016-01-12T07:58:08.9780981Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 14.0.23107.0
2016-01-12T07:58:08.9780981Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
2016-01-12T07:58:09.2437191Z Starting test execution, please wait...
2016-01-12T07:58:09.3062199Z Warning: Using Isolation mode to run the tests as diagnostic data adapters were enabled in the runsettings. Use the /inIsolation parameter to suppress this warning.
2016-01-12T07:58:14.2165110Z Information: Log Message: waiting for blanket... from D:\TFSAgent\_work\6\s\src\FSP.Tests\sampletests.js
2016-01-12T07:58:20.7009092Z Passed   SamleTest has a test
2016-01-12T07:58:20.7009092Z Passed   app testController has a controller defined
2016-01-12T07:58:20.7009092Z Passed   app testController echo returns same string
2016-01-12T07:58:20.7477777Z Results File: D:\TFSAgent\_work\6\TestResults\G04SEASLOID2$_G04SEASLOID2 2016-01-12 08_58_20.trx
2016-01-12T07:58:20.7477777Z Attachments:
2016-01-12T07:58:20.7477777Z   D:\TFSAgent\_work\6\TestResults\5f30d7de-bf10-44c2-b9f3-0640da2b8183\G04SEASLOID2$_G04SEASLOID2 2016-01-12 08_58_11.coverage
2016-01-12T07:58:20.7477777Z Total tests: 3. Passed: 3. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
2016-01-12T07:58:20.7477777Z Test Run Successful.
2016-01-12T07:58:20.7633997Z Test execution time: 8,2573 Seconds
2016-01-12T07:58:20.8883985Z Publishing Test Results...
2016-01-12T07:58:21.5290256Z Test results remaining: 3
2016-01-12T07:58:21.8415328Z Published Test Run : http://g04seasloid2:8181/tfs/DefaultCollection/FS%20Portal%20Project/_TestManagement/Runs#runId=272&_a=runCharts
```

The common.runsettings file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <ResultsDirectory>..\..\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
    <TargetPlatform>x86</TargetPlatform>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>Framework45</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </RunConfiguration>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
        <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>
            <ModulePaths>
              <Include>
              </Include>
              <Exclude>
                <ModulePath>.*\.tests\..*</ModulePath>
                <ModulePath>.*TestAdapter.*</ModulePath>
                <ModulePath>.*packages.*</ModulePath>
              </Exclude>
            </ModulePaths>
            <Functions>
              <Exclude>
                <Function>^Fabrikam\.UnitTest\..*</Function>
                <Function>^std::.*</Function>
                <Function>^ATL::.*</Function>
                <Function>.*::__GetTestMethodInfo.*</Function>
                <Function>^Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppCodeCoverageFramework::.*</Function>
                <Function>^Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::.*</Function>
              </Exclude>
            </Functions>
            <Attributes>
              <Exclude>
                <Attribute>^System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHiddenAttribute$</Attribute>
                <Attribute>^System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute$</Attribute>
                <Attribute>^System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute$</Attribute>
                <Attribute>^System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute$</Attribute>
                <Attribute>^System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute$</Attribute>
                <Attribute>^NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute$</Attribute>
                <Attribute>^Xunit.FactAttribute$</Attribute>
                <Attribute>^Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestClassAttribute$</Attribute>
              </Exclude>
            </Attributes>
            <Sources>
              <Exclude>
                <Source>.*\\atlmfc\\.*</Source>
                <Source>.*\\vctools\\.*</Source>
                <Source>.*\\public\\sdk\\.*</Source>
                <Source>.*\\microsoft sdks\\.*</Source>
                <Source>.*\\vc\\include\\.*</Source>
              </Exclude>
            </Sources>
            <CompanyNames>
              <Exclude>
                <CompanyName>.*microsoft.*</CompanyName>
              </Exclude>
            </CompanyNames>
            <PublicKeyTokens>
              <Exclude>
                <PublicKeyToken>^B77A5C561934E089$</PublicKeyToken>
                <PublicKeyToken>^B03F5F7F11D50A3A$</PublicKeyToken>
                <PublicKeyToken>^31BF3856AD364E35$</PublicKeyToken>
                <PublicKeyToken>^89845DCD8080CC91$</PublicKeyToken>
                <PublicKeyToken>^71E9BCE111E9429C$</PublicKeyToken>
                <PublicKeyToken>^8F50407C4E9E73B6$</PublicKeyToken>
                <PublicKeyToken>^E361AF139669C375$</PublicKeyToken>
              </Exclude>
            </PublicKeyTokens>
            <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>True</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>
            <AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>True</AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>
            <CollectFromChildProcesses>True</CollectFromChildProcesses>
            <CollectAspDotNet>False</CollectAspDotNet>
          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
  <MSTest>
    <MapInconclusiveToFailed>True</MapInconclusiveToFailed>
    <CaptureTraceOutput>false</CaptureTraceOutput>
    <DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>False</DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>
    <DeploymentEnabled>False</DeploymentEnabled>
  </MSTest>
  <ChutzpahAdapterSettings>
    <TestingMode>All</TestingMode>
  </ChutzpahAdapterSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

Some screenshots
[image: Build overview]
[image: Build step config]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [built-in code coverage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx) function in VS. No matter you are using XAML build or vNext build, you just need to enable the related settings in build definition.

For XAML build

[image]

For vNext build
[image]

Here is a blog introducing  [Continuous Integration with JavaScript, NUnit on TFSBuild](http://www.codit.eu/blog/2015/03/18/continuous-integration-with-javascript-nunit-on-tfsbuild-part-3-of-3-/), for your reference.

Comment: Hi Patrick. CodeCoverage is enabled and it works fine for dll, exe files. But not for Javascripts. TFS publishes a coverage file but on the build overview it states no code coverage, even though there are test results. I cant get my head around this.

Comment: Might this link will help you http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/07/09/javascript-unit-tests-on-team-foundation-service-with-chutzpah.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but for anyone else stumbling upon this in future:

This makes the assumption you are using Karma with VSTS "Build vNext" pipeline.

In order to get code coverage as part of your build, add a TrxReporter to your Karma.config.js as below

```
trxReporter: { outputFile: 'Javascrip-test-results.trx' shortTestName: false}
```

You can now configure a build task to run Karma as part of your build (i.e. NPM task), after that you can pick up the trx output with a "publish Test results" task.

For more detailed instructions see http://www.clemensreijnen.nl/post/2016/10/17/CICD-Pipeline-for-Angular2-with-VSTS